# Making an image fill the inside of a grid while maintaining aspect ratio

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to layout a portion of this site such that when the window is made wider/slimmer, the images automatically scale within their respective boxes, as to maintain their original aspect ratios.

You can see my code at the codepen, or below, I've tried incasing the images in DIVs, moving the div within the grid layout, and setting the image to use `width: 100, height: 100; imagefill: cover;` but it had seemingly no effect, it has worked for me on previous code blocks when encapsulating the image within a div, I'm having a hard time finding exactly what is going wrong this time... suggestions on how to make it work?

https://codepen.io/roomwillow/pen/YzNKQwO

HTML:

```
<div class="marketsContainerGrid">
    <h2 id="marketsHeader">Markets Served</h2>
    <div class="marketsChildGrid">
        <div class="marketObjects" id="marketObject1">
            <img class="servicesImages" src="https://placem.at/places?h=600">
            <h3>Box 1</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="marketObjects" id="marketObject2">
            <img class="servicesImages" src="https://placem.at/places?h=400">
            <h3>Box 2</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="marketObjects" id="marketObject3">
            <img class="servicesImages" src="https://placem.at/places?h=500">
            <h3>Box 3</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="marketObjects" id="marketObject4">
            <img class="servicesImages" src="https://placem.at/places?w=500">
            <h3>Box 4</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="marketObjects" id="marketObject5">
            <img class="servicesImages" src="https://placem.at/places?w=1800">
            <h3>Box 5</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="marketObjects" id="marketObject6">
            <img class="servicesImages" src="https://placem.at/places?h=1400">
            <h3>Box 6</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="marketObjects" id="marketObject7">
            <img class="servicesImages" src="https://placem.at/places?h=1800">
            <h3>Box 7</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="marketObjects" id="marketObject8">
            <img class="servicesImages" src="https://placem.at/places?h=600">
            <h3>Box 8</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="marketObjects" id="marketObject9">
            <img class="servicesImages" src="">
            <h3>Box 9</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="marketObjects" id="marketObject10">
            <img class="servicesImages" src="">
            <h3>Box 10</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="marketObjects" id="marketObject11">
            <img class="servicesImages" src="">
            <h3>Box 11</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="marketObjects" id="marketObject12">
            <img class="servicesImages" src="">
            <h3>Box 12</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="marketObjects" id="marketObject13">
            <img class="servicesImages" src="">
            <h3>Box 13</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="marketObjects" id="marketObject14">
            <img class="servicesImages" src="">
            <h3>Box 14</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="marketObjects" id="marketObject15">
            <img>
            <h3>Don't See What Your Looking For?</h3>
            <p>Reach out, and we'll see how best our services can help achieve your goals!</p>
            <a class="button1" id="servicesContactButton" href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

/*Text*/
h1{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 22pt;
}
h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  margin: 0;
}
h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18pt;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
}
p {
  font-size: 1.08rem;
    letter-spacing: 0.02em;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans serif;
  color: white;
}

/* Black on White */
.button1 {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem 0.5rem 1rem;
  border: solid white 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
.button1:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

/* White on Black */
.button2 {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem 0.5rem 1rem;
  border: solid black 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
.button2:hover {
  background-color: black;
    color: white;
}





/* Markets */
.marketsContainerGrid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 7rem auto;
}
#marketsHeader {
    color: black;
    justify-self: center;
    align-self: center;
}
.marketsChildGrid {
    grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 17.5rem 5rem 2.5rem 12.5rem 2.5rem 17.5rem;
    grid-template-columns: 20% 20% 20% 20% 20%;
}
.marketObjects {
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
}
.servicesImages {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    objectfit: cover;
    opacity: 85%;
    align-self: center;
    justify-self: center;
}
.marketObjects:hover img {
    transition: opacity 0.5s, width 1s, height 1s;
    opacity: 100%;
    width: 105%;
    height: 105%;
}
.marketObjects h3 {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    align-self: end;
    background-color: black;
    justify-self: start;
    z-index: 2;
}
#marketObject1 {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
}
#marketObject2 {
    grid-area: 2 / 1 / 6 / 2;
}
#marketObject3 {
    grid-area: 6 / 1 / 7 / 2;
}
#marketObject4 {
    grid-area: 1 / 2 / 3 / 3;
}
#marketObject5 {
    grid-area: 3 / 2 / 5 / 3;
}
#marketObject6 {
    grid-area: 5 / 2 / 7 / 3;
}
#marketObject7 {
    grid-area: 1 / 3 / 4 / 4;
}
#marketObject8 {
    grid-area: 4 / 3 / 6 / 3;
}
#marketObject9 {
    grid-area: 6 / 3 / 7 / 4;
}
#marketObject10 {
    grid-area: 1 / 4 / 2 / 5;
}
#marketObject11 {
    grid-area: 2 / 4 / 5 / 5;
}
#marketObject12 {
    grid-area: 5 / 4 / 7 / 5;
}
#marketObject13 {
    grid-area: 1 / 5 / 3 / 6;
}
#marketObject14 {
    grid-area: 3 / 5 / 6 / 6;
}
#marketObject15 {
    background-color: black;
    grid-area: 6 / 5 / 7 / 6;
    grid-template-rows: 35% 40% 25%;
    justfy-items: start;
    align-items: start;
}
#marketObject15 h3 {
    align-self: start;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 2rem 0 0 2rem;
    max-width: 80%;
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
}
#marketObject15 p {
    grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
    margin: 1rem 0 0 2rem;
    max-width: 80%;
    
}
#servicesContactButton {
    grid-area: 3 / 1 / 4 / 2;
    margin-left: 2rem;
    justify-self: start;
}
```

Comment: Do not use `grid-area` on `.servicesImages`. Use `grid-area` on parent of image `marketObjects` just set `width & height`: `100%` on images

Answer (score 0):

1. I think `flex` will make you life easier (instead of `grid`).
2. To keep the aspect ratio, use only `width` in you case `width: 100%`, `height` will force it to distort the shape based on the parent element.

---

I reduced the problem to just the image part.

Notice I changed the structure to fill the images into `<div class="column">` as the content seems to be static (6 colums), and just making it `width: 20%`, so you get rid of ~70% of the CSS code.

Also, use `transform: scale()` instead of changing the `width` to avoid layout changes (expensive/slow operations).

E.g.:

```css
/* Markets */

.marketsChildFlex {
  display: flex;
  background-color: black
}

.column {
  width: 20%;
}

.marketObjects {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.servicesImages {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 85%;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.marketObjects:hover img {
  transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 1s;
  opacity: 100%;
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.marketObjects h3 {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1rem;
  bottom: 1rem;
}


/* Base */

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}


/*Text*/

h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18pt;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans serif;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="marketsChildFlex">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="marketObjects" id="marketObject1">
      <img class="servicesImages" src="https://placem.at/places?h=600">
      <h3>Box 1</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="marketObjects" id="marketObject2">
      <img class="servicesImages" src="https://placem.at/places?h=400">
      <h3>Box 2</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="marketObjects" id="marketObject3">
      <img class="servicesImages" src="https://placem.at/places?h=500">
      <h3>Box 3</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="marketObjects" id="marketObject4">
      <img class="servicesImages" src="https://placem.at/places?w=500">
      <h3>Box 4</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="marketObjects" id="marketObject5">
      <img class="servicesImages" src="https://placem.at/places?w=1800">
      <h3>Box 5</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="marketObjects" id="marketObject6">
      <img class="servicesImages" src="https://placem.at/places?h=1400">
      <h3>Box 6</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="marketObjects" id="marketObject7">
      <img class="servicesImages" src="https://placem.at/places?h=1800">
      <h3>Box 7</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="marketObjects" id="marketObject8">
      <img class="servicesImages" src="https://placem.at/places?h=600">
      <h3>Box 8</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="marketObjects" id="marketObject9">
      <img class="servicesImages" src="https://placem.at/places?h=600">
      <h3>Box 9</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="marketObjects" id="marketObject10">
      <img class="servicesImages" src="https://placem.at/places?h=1400">
      <h3>Box 10</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="marketObjects" id="marketObject11">
      <img class="servicesImages" src="https://placem.at/places?h=1800">
      <h3>Box 11</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="marketObjects" id="marketObject12">
      <img class="servicesImages" src="https://placem.at/places?h=500">
      <h3>Box 12</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="marketObjects" id="marketObject13">
      <img class="servicesImages" src="https://placem.at/places?h=400">
      <h3>Box 13</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="marketObjects" id="marketObject14">
      <img class="servicesImages" src="https://placem.at/places?h=1400">
      <h3>Box 14</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the original solution was going to use flex, but because we don't want the aspect ratios of the boxes themselves to change, and because the tops and bottoms of neighbouring boxes have different Y values, it was ruled out

Comment: So, the images keep the aspect ratio, but the ratios of the boxes doesn't matter, what we want is: all the columns must have the same height. right?

Comment: Consider adding the specifications as detailed as you can to the question so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

The correct css property is "object-fit" not objectfit or imagefill.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit